# UWP C# - Progress bar on HTTP Request

Tags: c#, uwp

So currently I get a list of images with ID's. When the user then clicks on it, it downloads and displays the image. Everything works, I just need a progress bar to show where it is currently at.

Current code:

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "myPost", "Data" },
        };

        var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("test", "header");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("myScript.php", content);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using UWP. I would suggest you use the HttpClient provided in Windows.Web.Http. This has post/put and get methods which also provides progress.
See [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn298639) for more details specifically HttpProgress in HttpClient.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does this include custom headers and getting the response headers?

Comment: Yes the post async method returns  IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> where HttpResponseMessage class provides headers and HttpProgress will provide the progress